# How to check that any row in the square matrix has all 0s or 1s using 2d array in java

Tags: java

The java 2d array code below creates square matrix and randomly fills in  0s and 1s into the matrix. I need to find if any row in the matrix has all 0s or 1s, and then print the row number. How can I achieve this? Thank you!

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the size of the matrix: ");

    int sizeOfMatrix = input.nextInt();

    int[][] matrix = new int[sizeOfMatrix][4];


    for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < matrix[row].length; column++) {
            matrix[row][column] = (int)(Math.random() * 2);
            System.out.print(matrix[row][column]+ " "); 
        }           
            System.out.println();   
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean how do you do this? You wrote code that uses loops to initialize the values of the array, so you know how to use loops.. Now you need more looping code that checks each row.

Comment: Thank you, let me give it a try. I have been trying, but no luck so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after creating the 2D array the basic logic might be something like:

```
for (each row)
{
    int zeroes = 0;

    for (each column)
    {
        if (arrayValue == 0) zeroes++
    }

    if (zeroes == 0) System.out.println("All ones, row: " + row);

    if (zeroes == columnCount) System.out.println("All zeroes, row: " + row);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the logic, I am sure I will get it done now!

Comment: Your question was voted down by someone (not me), because you did not show that you made an effort to solve your problem. You stated in the comment you had been trying, but you did not show the code you tried. When you prove to people you have made an effort to solve a problem you will always get more help, then just asking us how to solve the problem.

Comment: what will be `columnCount` here?

Comment: The looping code is basically the same as your original code. How do you control the column looping in that code? Is that not the column count? The point of my answer was to get you to think about the concept of solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

here is the working code: Thank you @camickr

```
for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
        int zeros = 0;

        for (int column = 0; column < matrix[row].length; column++) {
            if(matrix[row][column] == 0) 
                zeros++;
        }           
            if(zeros == 0) 
                System.out.println("All ones, row: " + row);

            if(zeros == matrix[row].length) 
                System.out.println("All zeroes, row: " + row);                  
    }
```